# How do I make A Windows Computer recognize an APK File without installing Bluestacks?

Tags: android

APK Files aren't recognizable files like executable files; they won’t run on a double click. That's why we need a player/emulator like Bluestacks/Andy/Droid to play them.

So what should I do to extract all the info about an APK without installing it and running it on a device?

Comment: APK is not the same as EXE. It is designed for Android only. Voting to close. Also, question clearly shows you have done no research into the understanding of APK's.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "extract all the info about an APK" means and what that has to do with Windows or Bluestacks.

Comment: Do you mean extract like a zip file?

Comment: Do you mean "open the files in the APK as if it were a folder in windows explorer so that I can view the file contents"? that's what I got out of this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can get some limited information about an APK by extracting it. An APK is essentially a zip file containing manifest, resources, assets and classes which together make up the application. Change the `.apk' extension to`.zip` and extract it using built-in Windows tools. Note that most contents won't be human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

## APK-Info

APK-Info is a Windows tool to get detailed info about an apk file.

[image: APK-Info]

Allows you to view:

- application icon
- package name
- name (in all languages)
- version
- build number
- the minimum, maximum, and target version of the SDK (Android)
- supported density (DPI) and screen size
- architecture (ABI)
- supported textures
- permissions
- features
- signature
- OpenGL ES version
- whether app supports Android TV, Wear OS, and/or Android Auto
- locales
- a variety of hashes (MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512)
- and a lot of other information

## Using

You can open the APK file in APK-Info using one of the following methods:

- Start APK-Info, and then select the APK file in the dialog.
- Open the APK file by clicking on the open button in the dialog.
- Drag the APK file to APK-Info.exe or its shortcut.
- Drag the APK file into the running APK-Info window.
- Open the APK file by double-clicking, after installing APK-Info, as a program for opening APK files (via explorer or attached .cmd file).

https://github.com/Enyby/APK-Info

Comment: That deserves a -1 from me. Telling the OP to go elsewhere to get the info on apk without any clear explanation on what/how it works.

Comment: I answered the question "So what should I do to extract all the info about an APK without installing it and running it on a device?" I gave him the link to the download link so what should I do anymore ?

Comment: Brahim, I am equally confused what to do in this situation. The answer to the OP's question requires that 1) links to another other site that, 2) provides an executable. How should this question be answered without asking the user to go elsewhere and download something?